# Inno Setup detect number of processors

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to detect the number of processors/cores using Inno Setup? It doesn't appear to be a built-in function and I am unable to find any information on this. Does anyone have a ready-made solution or point me in the direction of how to approach coding such a function?

Comment: I would query WMI for this information.

Comment: The NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS environment variable

Comment: Isn't the %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% Environment Variable set at the time of Windows installation? i.e. if another processor has been added since Windows was installed or if an image was taken from another machine this could be incorrect?

Comment: AFAIK the hardware variables are all set at boot time

Comment: @AlexK. Thanks, I have now tested this by temporarily switching multiple core support off in the BIOS and it does appear that the hardware variables are set at boot time, as it was reporting 4 before and now reports 1 after. Switching back on returns 4 again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The %NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS% Environment Variable can be used. Thanks @AlexK.